# Those managing development teams

Tags: relative-pronouns, reduced-relative-clauses

Would it be correct to say/write:

> These are the essential skills for **those managing** development teams.

meaning:

> These are the essential skills for **those who are managing** development teams.

And would it be also correct to say/write:

> These are the essential skills for **those manage** development teams.

meaning:

> These are the essential skills for **those who manage** development teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct, the second is not.

I'm struggling to think of a good explanation for this, other than to say that the second meaning is more abstract, as it doesn't explicitly tell us whether or not the people are currently managing development teams; it is more of a general statement.

Also:

> Those manage development teams.

This is a complete sentence in itself (a basic factual statement) - though to refer to people you would say "they" and not "those".

> Those managing development teams.

This entire statement denotes the "managers", but doesn't actually say anything about them, and so is not a complete statement. It can also be injected as a single collective noun, as you have done above:

> These are the essential skills for **those managing development teams**.